# How to link OpenAL on the command line (OS X)

Tags: macos, clang, openal, osx-lion

I'm trying to compile a project which is using OpenAL on Mac OS X 10.7. If I would be using XCode I could link the OpenAL.framework, but in the directory

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenAL.framework/
```

theres no subdirectory called 'Libraries'. So what should I link against?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is just a generic answer to link frameworks in the Mac, it should work for OpenAL.framework

```
% gcc -framework OpenAL -o test test.c
```

Also see this old [GCC article](http://developer.apple.com/tools/gcc_overview.html)